# How do I pass a whole class as a parameter to another class`s method

Tags: python

Is it possible to pass a whole class (not an instance) as a parameter to another class method in Python? If I have several instances of the class first and need to pass any of them not specifying which one to method of class Second, can I do something like this:

```
class First():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        pass

class Second():
    def __init__(self, c, d):
        pass
    def method(self, First):
        #and how do I call here the whole class First
        #without calling a particular instance here?
```

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: To reinforce @karthikr's question, can you tell us why you need to pass the first class to a method? If we know more broadly what you are trying to achieve, we can tailor our answers to your specific situation.

Comment: As a side note: while `class First():` is legal it raises a red flag. If you're using Python 2.x, it creates a classic class, which you don't want. And, whether you're using 2.x or 3.x, it has exactly the same meaning to the interpreter as `class First:`, but it signals to the human reader either (a) "the designer of this class doesn't know Python" or (b) "this class is following a particular coding standard that recommends empty parentheses to explicitly warn that it's a classic class".

Answer (score 3):

Straightforward.

```
def method(self, First):
    First() #instantiation
    First.classmethod()
    First.staticmethod()
```

In python classes are objects itself, so you are able to call your `method` like this

```
second_instance.method(Any_Class_You_Want)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't need to specify types in Python. So, if you want `method` to take a `First` instance, just do this:

```
class Second():
    def __init__(self, c, d):
        pass
    def method(self, first):
        pass

my_first = First(0, 1)
my_second = Second(2, 3)
my_second.method(my_first)
```

I believe that answers your real question, which is:

> If I have several instances of the class first and need to pass any of them not specifying which one to method of class Second…

If you want to ensure that the parameter actually is a First, you can always add an `assert isinstance(first, First)` or `if not isinstance(first, First): raise TypeError` or whatever, but usually you don't want to do that in Python. The whole point of "duck typing" is that you write a function that takes "anything that acts like a `First` instance" rather than a function that takes "a `First` instance".

---

You then say:

> Now I need to mutate variables from the First class inside the method of a second class:

So… just do it. Your example doesn't have any attributes in the `First` class, so let's add some:

```
class First():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.total = a + b
```

And now, let's use them in `Second.method`:

```
class Second():
    def __init__(self, c, d):
        self.total = c + d
    def method(self, first):
        first.total += self.total
```

So:

```
>>> my_first = First(0, 1)
>>> my_first.total
1
>>> my_second = Second(2, 3)
>>> my_second.total
5
>>> my_first.total += 2
>>> my_first.total
3
>>> my_second.method(my_first)
>>> my_first.total
8
```

---

Or, if you meant that you wanted to mutate the *class* attributes in class `First`… you don't even need a `First` instance for that:

```
First.my_class_attribute = 1
```

---

If you really *do* need to pass a class itself… well, a class is a regular value like anything else:

```
class Second():
    def __init__(self, c, d):
        pass
    def method(self, cls):
        pass

my_second = Second(1, 2)
my_second.method(First)
```

And you can access the class attributes of `cls` from within `method`, just as easily as you can access instance attributes when an instance is passed.

Comment: Now I need to mutate variables from the First class inside the method of a second class:

Comment: So? Just do it! If you're doing the first version, where you have an object that should be a `First` instance, you can mutate its attributes through normal dot-syntax (or any other way you prefer). If you're doing the second, where you have an object that should be the `First` class itself, obviously you can only mutate the class attributes, both otherwise, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
class Model1:

    def get():
        return '1'

class Model2:
    def get(Model1):
        print('test: '+ str(Model1.get()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Model2.get(Model1)
```

the output is;: `test: 1`